# Is the controls in android is not publicly accessible within that activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is the controls in android is not publicly accessible within that activity (.java file)

Here the edittext field **txt1** - I want to access it in a function **public void clr()**

How can I do it? Is it possible or am doing something wrong?

This may be a very basic qn. But I am quite new to Java & Android - though experienced in C#. Pl help

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        final EditText txt1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText txt2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Some code here

            }
        });

        Button btnClr=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnClr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                txt1.setText("");
                txt2.setText("");

                res.setText("");

                txt1.requestFocus();

            }
        });


    }


    public void clr(){

        txt1.setText("");
        txt2.setText("");

        res.setText("");

        txt1.requestFocus();

    }
```

I know I can pass txt1, txt2 as arguments to the clr function. But I would like to know whether the above mentioned is posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
TextView res;
EditText txt1;
EditText txt2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txt1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txt2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Some code here

        }
    });

    Button btnClr=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnClr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            clr();

        }
    });


}


public void clr(){

    txt1.setText("");
    txt2.setText("");

    res.setText("");

    txt1.requestFocus();

}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Me tubelight :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the EditText field on the class level, then the variable txt1 would be visible in your clr() method.

Comment: I am declaring it in the same class only... Inside public class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: I meant inside the class itself, not in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

First thing that C# developers feel difficult to understand with android is, controls. Visual studio provides designer to put controls and as you put control on the form it automatically creates instance of respective class and makes it accessible. It creates a partial class which after combining your code behind, creates a complete class.

With android, it is your responsibility to create variables as it does not create variable by itself. The designer is merely a screen layout and you cannot access it. The standard way to do it is to create a variable of type what you want to  access in your class and then assign the control by using findbyid to access that control.

The variables you defined can have their own scope. So if you make it accessible class wide then it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the EditText at Class level:

```
     Class MyClass extends Activity {

     final EditText txt1;

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            txt1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not new to programming,then you should know you must declared variable as global within that class to access it in any method.You should declared it inside class.but outside any particular method.

Comment: Yes. I tried this - I made both the fn & textedit as public - but It is not allowing textedit to be public (public EditText txt1). It shows the error - illegal modifier present

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error in your code is because of the fact that

Scope of final variable declared inside the method is within the method only.
It can not be accessed outside the method.The final local variable is indeed destroyed after the method returns...

so you have to make your edittext variable of your class level...

see thats why you are not getting access here

```
 public void clr(){

    txt1.setText("");
    txt2.setText("");

    res.setText("");

    txt1.requestFocus();

}
```

Comment: Not global.  Never make Activity resources global, it's asking for trouble.